# Very simple (?) dice question

Tags: probability, dice

We were just discussing with colleagues the number of combinations you could get with two "normal", $6$-sided dice. Almost all of my colleagues were saying $36$ ($6^2$), which I agree with as such, but you will get almost half of the possible combinations counted twice. 
If I count, the number of different combinations with $2$ dice is $21.$ I'm not able though to get to the formula that would let me calculate this for $3,4,5$ or more dice.

I remember from my old mathematics courses that there are several different formulas you can "pick" depending on repetition, order importance, etc...
What would be the appropriate formula taking into account $n$ as the number of dice and $s$ the number of sides ?

Comment: @drhab : You're forgetting $(1,1)$, ..., $(6,6)$.

Comment: @Plop thank you. Removed.

Comment: Generating functions ...? ... not too good with those ....

Comment: @Laurent : With $3$ dice, would you like to count $(1,2,2)$ and $(2,2,1)$ as one ?

Comment: @Bram28 : So... Yes ?

Comment: @Plop Oh my! Sorry, I misread your comment. :P So yes, count as one.

Answer (score 4):

If order doesn't count, then consider the following setup (I will do it for three 6-sided dice, but it can easily be generalized):

Put up five dividers ("bars"):
$$
|\quad|\quad|\quad|\quad|
$$
These five bars give us six regions (four gaps between the bars, as well as to the left and to the right). Each region corresponds to a number from 1 to 6 (say from left to right). Now distribute 3 $*$'s ("stars") in these six regions in any way you want. Each star corresponds to the result of a die. For instance, a throw of $3, 3, 4$ looks like
$$
|\quad|{}*{}*{}|{}*{}|\quad|
$$
This way each die throw corresponds to one ordering of 3 stars and 5 bars, and each ordering of stars and bars corresponds to a die throw.

The ordering of $3$ stars and $5$ bars can be thought of this way: You have $8$ available spots for any of the two symbols, and you want to choose $3$ of those spost to contain a star (the remaining $5$ will get bars). That can be done in $\binom{8}{3} = 56$ ways.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed explanation, it really helped me to better understand stars and bars application. I wrote a program to get all unique dice rolls and the answer is indeed 56.

Answer (score 3):

It agrees with the number of sums $a_1+\cdots+a_s=n$ where the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers.

Here $a_i$ stands for the number of dice that show face $i$.

Applying [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we find $$\binom{n+s-1}{s-1}$$possibilities.

Comment: So when $s=6$ this gives ${n +5 \choose 5}$, and when $n=2$ then ${7 \choose 5}=21$ as expected

Comment: Yes. That is a confirmation. Further it agrees with @Arthurs answer for the case $n=3,s=6$ because $\binom83=\binom85$.